# dictionary multiple key possibility?

Tags: ios, swift

Working with dictionaries, is it possible to assign two key values to a value range? Or should I be using an alternative method to achieve this other than dictionaries?

currently I have the following code;

```
let airlines =
[
    "TOM": ["Thomson"],
    "TCX": ["Thomas Cook"],
    "MON": ["Monarch"],
]
```

But I have a problem where by sometimes a different code will be used to call the same airline. For instance "Monarch" is "MON" but could also be "ZB". I have seen some suggestions about defining it as an array?

if this is a solution how would it effect my check up if any?

```
name = airlines[dataFetched]![0]
```

I did a test as follows in playground

```
["MON", "ZB"]: ["Monarch"],
```

which seems to work but my check up doesn't seem to be checking each section of the array so is assuming it's not there.

Comment: Why not just add `"ZB": ["Monarch"]` to your original dictionary?

Comment: Also is there a reason that your dictionary values are contained in arrays? Surely each airline code corresponds to a single airline only? Just use a `[String:String]` dictionary to map airline codes to airline names, with `"Monarch"` getting added for both the key `"MON"` and `"ZB"`.

Comment: @originaluser2 at the moment there is no reason for the array but I intend to expand the information available hence the array. But currently there is no reason. As for having two separate keys that indeed would work but would mean I would have to make sure I updated both "MON and "ZB" keys with any changes to array information in the future. It would be nice to know that these we're instead grouped. It's one of those that the solution is there but I just wondered if there was a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: @A.Denis If you want to add extra information to the airlines, then I would consider using an `Airline` struct instead of an array. You may also want to consider using a plist file in order to define this data – you could then structure it as an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary would represent an airline, having a `"name"` key and a `"codes"` key, where the value of the latter would be an array of airline code strings. You could then load this data into your app and then transform it into a `[String:Airline]`. If you want the values to be mutable, you could use a class for your airline.

Comment: @originaluser2 actually I was just looking at plist's now and I think what you said makes sense. Going to have a detailed look at it all now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you figure it out?